# What does a King wear?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

Should I call it *outfit* or what?

[image: cartoon king caped and crowned holding his rod of office in his right hand]

Comment: What did the thesaurus say?

Comment: The king in your picture is wearing a royal robe or royal garments.  Kings and Queens today wear pretty much what ordinary people wear, uniforms, suits, gowns, dresses, suits, maybe even more casual clothes.  When they are being crowned, they wear coronation robes.  There may also be other highly formal and symbolic occasions in which they wear royal robes.

Comment: @tchrist how does one find on thesaurus, if they don't know what to look for. Put "King's wear" or "King's outfit" in thesaurus. It gives zero result.

Comment: @ubihatt We expect people to use Google first before coming here.

Comment: @tchrist they did and they were routed here. Also, OP is a new user. They might not know the SE guidelines.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you provide an example sentence in which you would use this term?

Comment: @tchrist♦:  I believe the agreement was that works of general reference should be consulted, and that Google wasn't a work of general reference. I do feel that it would be preferable for the original poster to provide an example sentence with a blank. As this user is new, I think we should not put the question on hold before he has had a chance to edit his question.

Comment: @Cerberus I was hoping our site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts could aim higher here than **a thesaurus with votes**, which is all this question is going to provoke as answers.  We place questions on hold pending improvement, so just ping me if it improves.

Comment: Maybe you should ask something like "What's a word to describe what this king is wearing?" And add a little bit extra to the question such as your own research. Then it MAY be reopened. Lots of people here don't like a simple single line questions, despite the fact you've provided a pretty picture also. Oh yeah, and example sentences are pretty much a requirement for single-word-requests.

Comment: The obvious answer is 'regalia'...are you working a crossword puzzle?

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I appreciate you all for taking a time out of your day and helping me.